# Searching an ordered "list" matching condition when nothing matches the condition, list length = 1

Tags: r

I have a sorted list with 3 columns, and I'm searching to see if the second column matches 2 or 4, then returning the first column's element if so, and putting that into a function.

```
noOutliers((L1LeanList[order(L1LeanList[,1]),])[(L1LeanList[order(L1LeanList[,1]),2]==2)|
                                                (L1LeanList[order(L1LeanList[,1]),2]==4),1])
```

when nothing matches the condition. I get a

```
Error in ((L1LeanList[order(L1LeanList[, 1]), ])[1, ])[(L1LeanList[order(L1LeanList[,  : 
  incorrect number of dimensions
```

due to the fact that we effectively have List[List[all false]]

I can't just sub out something like L1LLSorted<-(L1LeanList[order(L1LeanList[,1]),]
and use L1LLSorted[,2] since this returns an error when the list is of length exactly 1

so now my code would need to look like

```
noOutliers(ifelse(any((L1LeanList[order(L1LeanList[,1]),2]==2)|
                      (L1LeanList[order(L1LeanList[,1]),2]==4)),0,
                      (L1LeanList[order(L1LeanList[,1]),])[(L1LeanList[order(L1LeanList[,1]),2]==2)|
                                                           (L1LeanList[order(L1LeanList[,1]),2]==4),1])))
```

which seems a bit ridiculous for the simple thing I'm requesting. 
while writing this I realized that I can end up putting all this error checking into the noOutliers function  itself so it looks like 
    noOutliers(L1LeanList,2,2,4) which will look much better, a necessity since slightly varying versions of this appear in my code dozens of times. I can't help but wonder, still, if theres a more elegant way to write the actual function.

for the curious, noOutliers finds a mean of the 30th-70th percentile in the sorted data set like so

```
noOutliers<-function(oList)
{
if (length(oList)<=20) return ("insufficient data")
cumSum<-0
iterCount<-0
for(i in round(length(oList)*3/10-.000001):round(length(oList)*7/10+.000001)+1)#adjustments deal with .5->even number rounding r mishandling
{                                                                              #and 1-based indexing (ex. for a list 1-10, taking 3-7 cuts off 1,2,8,9,10, imbalanced.)
  cumSum<-cumSum+oList[i]
  iterCount<-iterCount+1
}
return(cumSum/iterCount)
```

}

Comment: Please excuse me for being obtuse, but I do not see a data test case. All I see are failed attempts.

Comment: they are working attempts. I'm looking for an alternative working attempt. My code is getting really lengthy due to this and it looks pretty bad. Worse, its probably inefficient

Comment: can you provide some data to run your code?

Answer (score 0):

Let's see...

```
foo <- bar[(bar[,2]==2 | bar[,2]==4),1]
```

should extract all the first-column values you want.  Then run whatever function you want on `foo` perhaps with the caveat "if (length(foo) < 1) then {exit, or skip, or something} "